# Grunt: grunt-hub isn't watching all projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, gruntjs, dir

I've installed [grunt-hub](https://github.com/shama/grunt-hub) into my workspace, which looks like this

```
hub/
node_modules/
    grunt/
    grunt-hub/
Gruntfile.js
package.json
```

In Gruntfile.js I have written this,

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    'use strict';
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg : grunt.file.readJSON( 'package.json' ),
        hub: {
            src: [
                'hub/*/Gruntfile.js'
            ],
            watch: {
                src: '<%= hub.src %>',
                tasks: ['watch']
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-hub');
    grunt.registerTask('default', []);
}
```

I have four files within the hub directory, which have their own Gruntfiles.

```
hub/
    project1/
        ...
        Gruntfile.js
        ...
    project2/
        ...
        Gruntfile.js
        ...
    project3/
        ...
        Gruntfile.js
        ...
    project4/
        ...
        Gruntfile.js
        ...
```

When I run...

```
grunt hub
```

...it works perfectly fine; it watches all the changes I make and runs how I've commanded them to run.

The only problem is in the command prompt I am told...

```
>> C:\Grunt\hub\project1\Gruntfile.js:

Running "watch" task
Waiting...

>> C:\Grunt\hub\project2\Gruntfile.js:

Running "watch" task
Waiting...

>> C:\Grunt\hub\project3\Gruntfile.js:

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

...but am not told that project4 is being watched. When I make changes to files relating to project4, nothing happens, whereas it does for everything else.

What can I do to make it watch project4 as well?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing options.concurrent as per https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-hub

Answer (score 0):

The livereload has an effect on this. Here are some options:

- Add the watch task to your tasks list in your hub task config (grunt.config.hub.js):

  ```
          watch: {
                  options: {
                          allowSelf: true
                  },
                  src: hubSettings.src,
                  tasks: ['watch']
          },
  ```

OR:

- Run `grunt hub` with the watch task set as default: `grunt hub:target:watch`

**References**

- [grunt-hub issue #28: Doesn't support grunt-contrib-watch option livereload:true](https://github.com/shama/grunt-hub/issues/28)
- [Multi module JavaScript project with Grunt](http://lkrnac.net/blog/2014/05/multi-module-javascript-project/)

Answer (score 0):

I have this working in the following way:

```
    // scss files to watch ##
    watch_scss: [
        'wp-content/themes/**/*.scss', // regex to track all sass files in themes ##
        'wp-content/plugins/**/*.scss', // regex to track all sass files in plugins ##
    ],

    // grunt hub - master controller ##
    hub: {
        all: {
            options: {
                allowSelf: true,
            },
            src: [
                'Gruntfile.js', // this grunt file ##
                'wp-content/themes/**/Gruntfile.js', // in themes ##
                'wp-content/plugins/**/Gruntfile.js' // in plugins ##
            ],
            tasks: [ 'default' ]
        },
    },

    // watch task ##
    'watch': {
        // track changes to scss src files ##
        'sass': {
            'options': {
                'livereload': 1337, // dedicated port for live reload ##
                'debounceDelay': 5000, // wait a little for sass to complete ##
            },
            'files':
                '<%= watch_scss %>' // files defined in config ##
            ,
            'tasks': [
                [],  // nada ##
            ]
        },`
```

Be sure to include grunt-watch task:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-contrib-watch' ); // Watcher ##
```

And define a grunt task for default:

```
grunt.registerTask( 'default', [
    'watch', // watch ##
]);
```

Make sure your individual gruntfiles don't also have livereload option on watch tasks, then run "grunt hub:all:watch"